# Authenticate against a web service using AFNetworking 2

Tags: afnetworking-2

I need to authenticate against a web service hosted on Domino Lotus Notes. I can get data from the web service and process it. I modified the code that does that and it works, but I really don't think I am doing it the correct way.

I will have the user enter their username and password, and then call this code below. If the success block is executed I will store their user name and password, if it is failure I will alert them and have them try again.

My questions are

1) What is the URL and method to just authenticate and return back a yes or no? I cannot find it?

2) Is there a way to do this NOT in blocks, or is there a way to stop the user from doing something until I get the block returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
     AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager =
          [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
      manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
      [manager.requestSerializer
          setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"XXXX"
                                         password:@"XXXX"];
      manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

      AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
          [manager GET:@"https:/xxxxxxxxxxmobile/mobilede.nsf/"
                       @"restContacts.xsp/Contacts?OpenWebService"
              parameters:[self jsonDict]
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,
                        id responseObject) { NSLog(@"Success"); }
              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"Failure");
                  ;
              }];
      [operation start];
```

Comment: Can you post some sort of API docs you are willing to access?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking? API docs? Are you saying the API Docs for AFNetworking?

Comment: API docs for the Webservice API -> https://apps.scoular.com/mobile/mobilede.nsf/

I just wanted to check what auth mechanism restContacts.xsp/Contacts?OpenWebService is using. Is it using basic http auth?

Comment: The web service is in a Lotus Notes Domino database. It returns JSON. Does this help?

Comment: @BryanSchmiedeler, are you talking about using the Domino Data Service, a Control (xe:restService), or something custom (e.g.- Java servlet, X/Agent, etc)?